# Find reference to context menu items in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, context-menu

So I got the famous issue with Windows 8 context menu items. I've tried manually, with CCleaner, With Glary utility 3. And I still have some issues.

Here is an example for a right click on a .jpg:

[image: Context menu .jpg]

For the .jpg I can't seem to find any associations. Here is a SS from regedit HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT:

[image: Regedit .jpg]

Comment: did you try updating your graphic drivers form device manager  ?

Comment: @FahadSaleem it just tells me it's up to date.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? What value do you have next to `.jpg` in `(Default)`? You should look that value up under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.

Comment: @Rik In HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/.jpg there is a (Default) with following value: IrfanView.jpg

Comment: And what is the issue? Looks like your default program for .jpg is IrfanView. If something is wrong you can look in that key (`IrfanView.jpg`). (for me it says `jpegfile`) (I'm not familiar with what the `famous issue with Windows 8 context menu items` is)

Comment: @Rik Thanks a ton. I went inside irfanview and found irfanview.jpg in there was the shell >_< If you could put in an answer with a little more text I'll reward you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the context-menus work is (simplified) like this:

You look in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` for your file-extension (i.e. `.jpg`). It will contain a string value in `(Default)`.

[image]

Sometimes you have all the information under this key. If not then you need to look up the value of `(Default)` in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` (i.e. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/jpegfile`).

[image]

There it will have all the context-entries you're looking for. You can edit them there.

Comment: I don't get why microsoft haven't made one place the user can go to easily change these settings. Lets say I wanted to change it for all images... That would take forever.

Comment: They can't make it too easy. That's what programmers are for :) Kidding aside, they have made it so you can choose "Open with" and choose a different program (and if "Open with" is not there you can press shift and then right-click) but you're right, this has to be done per image-type. Normally this should be done by the program with which you want to associate it with (because it knows all the types it can support) but if things are screwed up you need to go digging (or re-install the application if it doesn't have a re-associate function).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Open Registry Editor

Now navigate to this directory:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers

[image]

Delete  every folder in that directory  except "New Folder"

Now Close the reg editor and see if it works